# Deploy app with NoSQL database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql, relational-database, publish

I usually work with relational databases. Recently I've been learning how to use NoSQL : More precisely MongoDB with NodeJS.

Due to my experience with relational databases; If we code an application locally, when we deploy our application we have to also host the relational database on the server (or a server) in order to be able to connect them.

Now with NodeJS I created a basic app that communicates with a database and one collection in MongoDB. I published my NodeJS app on a debian server and it is now online and running.

What I am wondering about is if there is the same procedure for NoSQL that exists for relational databases : 
Should I deploy the DB / publish it to the server? and if so what is the procedure?

Thank you and sorry I am still a beginner at this

Comment: You just need to install mongodb either on same server or different server, if you are installing on different server then you have enable remote access with security like RDBMS

Comment: One thing: NoSQL databases are not a homogenous set. My first job (in 1978) was on the development team of a database system called IDMS. It would nowadays be regarded as a NoSQL database, it was quite unlike any dbms available today. Today there are dbms's like MongoDB that are largely schemaless, there are also graph dbs that model themselves on the mathematics of graph theory.

Comment: @ArifKhan Is it enough if i installed mongodb on the same server ? do i have to manually create the db and collection?

Comment: Just install mongodb, you do not need to create db or collection

Comment: @HelpASisterOut May I suggest having a look at https://www.infoq.com/articles/mongodb-deployment-monitoring

Comment: @PaulaThomas I already checked that link before posting my question; it's mostly about theory and best practices, i couldn't find an answer to my question in it. And i subscribed to the practical course suggested by them but i can't hold till the course starts to have an answer :)